# Why can't I send arguments as reference to thread function?

Tags: c++, stdthread

I have the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

void func(std::string& str)
{
    std::string to_change("Bye...");
    std::cout << "From func: " << str << std::endl;
    str.swap(to_change);
}

int main()
{
    std::string Meeting = "Hi!";
    std::thread t1(func, Meeting);
    t1.join();

    std::cout << "From main: " << Meeting << std::endl;


    Sleep(20000);
    return 1;
}
```

The output is:

> From func: HI
>
> From main: HI

But if I do this type of moving by reference:

```
std::ref(Meeting)
```

Then the output goes:

> From func: HI
>
> From main: Bye...

What are the difference between sending the both reference types?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile with gcc or clang, which leads me to believe that it compiles under (presumably) MSVC due to some nonstandard extensions.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Comment: Might not be the best link for a duplicate. But the answer still applies: thread always intentionally copies the passed thread arguments.